# How to merge two objects using angularjs or simple javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two objects

```
$scope.a= {"Sedan":{"Audi":["A3","A4"]},"Hatchback":{"Maruthi":["Swift"]}}; 
var b= {"Hatchback":{"Volkswagen":["Polo"],"Fiat":["Punto1"]}};
```

I need the following result after merging

```
{"Sedan":{"Audi":["A3","A4"]},"Hatchback":{"Maruthi":["Swift"],"Volkswagen":["Polo"],"Fiat":["Punto1"]}};
```

Comment: If you're using lodash, [_.merge](https://lodash.com/docs#merge) will suit your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this..

```
$scope.a= {"Sedan":{"Audi":["A3","A4"]},"Hatchback":{"Maruthi":["Swift"]}}; 
var b= {"Hatchback":{"Volkswagen":["Polo"],"Fiat":["Punto1"]}};

 var mergedobj= angular.merge($scope.a, b); //merge object b into $scope.a
```

see working plunkr here 
http://plnkr.co/edit/VpHwERUmLqx6MlwQj6JB?p=preview

Comment: If $scope.a= {"Sedan":{"Audi":["A3","A4"]},"Hatchback":{"Maruthi":["Swift"]}}; and var b = var b= {"Hatchback":{"Volkswagen":["Polo"],"Fiat":["Punto1"]}}; I am expecting this: {"Sedan":{"Audi":["A3","A4"]},"Hatchback":{"Maruthi":["Swift"],"Volkswagen":["Po‌​lo"],"Fiat":["Punto1"]}}

Answer (score 1):

Use angular.merge

```
  $scope.object = angular.merge($scope.a, b)
```

Comment: Thanks for your fiddle. If $scope.a= {"Sedan":{"Audi":["A3","A4"]},"Hatchback":{"Maruthi":["Swift"]}}; it is not giving the desired output in this case.

Comment: If $scope.a= {"Sedan":{"Audi":["A3","A4"]},"Hatchback":{"Maruthi":["Swift"]}}; and var b = var b= {"Hatchback":{"Volkswagen":["Polo"],"Fiat":["Punto1"]}}; I am expecting this: {"Sedan":{"Audi":["A3","A4"]},"Hatchback":{"Maruthi":["Swift"],"Volkswagen":["Polo"],"Fiat":["Punto1"]}}

Comment: any idea regarding this?

Comment: use angular.merge($scope.a,b)

Answer (score 0):

Try below snippet

```
$scope.extend(obj, src) {
    for (var key in src) {
       if (src.hasOwnProperty(key)) obj[key] = src[key];
    }
    return obj;
}
```

To merge the objects

```
$scope.extend($scope.a, b);
```

Or you can use direct jQuery function. Please make sure you should have loaded the jquery min prior to your angular min js. After loading jquery min on the DOM, please call below jQuery function

```
var newObj = $.extend(true, $scope.a, b);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need a new object as a result try this:

```
 var c = {};
 angular.extend(c, $scope.a, b);
```

or you can do this:

```
 angular.extend($scope.a, b);
```

`$scope.a` will contain the merged result.

Comment: It is giving back the object $scope.a

Comment: Please see the updated question... sorry for the late edit.